# Django admin adding ajax functionality

Tags: django

While the Django admin is great for getting projects up and running quickly, I find it hard to customise it exactly to my liking.

One example of this is a situation where the user selects if the model in question has a parent. If the answer is True, you might want to display (via Ajax), a select dropdown asking if this model is to be shown in the main menu. If the answer to the question was False, you would not show the select dropdown, and set the value of this field (inMainMenu) to False (this could be done in the model). These fields of course do not have a Foreign Key relationship, so it's not a question of dependent dropdowns.

Is there a simple solution to this problem?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions

Comment: Thanks for getting back - is adding custom javascript through the media class the only way to do this?

Comment: Hi, not really used the media class for models in admin - it's absolutely fine - thank you